# How can I reliably determine the hardware version of a VMWare Guest from inside the guest?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am attempting to determine the "hardware" version of numerous VMWare VMs.  I don't have access to the vSphere console.

The VMWare Tools Service is installed, and `C:\Program Files\VMWare\VMWare Tools\vmtoolsd.exe --cmd "info-get"` looks promising, however I cannot find any details about what key name to specify.

Is there some other method such as looking at VMWare device driver versions or perhaps a `wmic` query?

Comment: Why don't you have access to the console, and what do you intend to do with the hardware version information once you have it? Can you provide a little more context on the end goal?

Comment: I was attempting to audit the configuration of hundreds of VMs - looking for anomalies that might explain performance issues on some of them.  I have access to run executables in the VMs, and was hoping to exploit that ability as a way to understand exactly how the host is configured.

Comment: No problem - I'm working on something where we actually do have access to vsphere; but querying it for the hardware information would dramatically slow down the process - I would want to query the host itself to get the hardware info (and some other info as well). We already do this with VMWareToolboxCmd.exe to get ballooned memory.

Comment: @HannahVernon This is basically a case for vRealize Operations or some high-level VM management tool. The VM hardware level beyond a certain point won't have many performance implications.

Comment: There is a lot of info about the vmtoolsd command, but it appears to be related to vApp/OVF options. The proper syntax is `--cmd "info-get guestinfo.<variable>"` where <variable> is a custom variable set under the vApp options. Google "vmtoolsd guestinfo" for more information. I also tried correlating the BIOS version to the hardware version and didn't find anything useful. I think your best bet may PowerCLI or a Perl script. I would also work with your VMware administrators to generate a report. VM Hardware level doesn't generally have performance implicications anymore as ewwhite said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory what you are asking should be possible.

however it appears it isn't particularly well implemented by VMWare.

The extended options should be query-able from the guest with VMToolsd.exe available, as you correctly say. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
vmtoolsd.exe --cmd "info-get virtualHW.version"
```

Should return the hardware version contained in the vmx file, however it doesn't.

a post in this thread by simonbaev seems to highlight a problem, requiring hypervisor level changes to allow this information to be queried from the guest :
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2184934

```
$ vmware-cmd --config esxi-24 "[DS_104.24_150] LTSP2/LTSP2.vmx" setguestinfo myTest "hello world"  
setguestinfo(myTest hello world) = 1  
$ vmware-cmd --config esxi-24 "[DS_104.24_150] LTSP2/LTSP2.vmx" getguestinfo myTest  
getguestinfo(myTest) = hello world  
$ vmtoolsd --cmd "info-get guestinfo.myTest"  
No value found  
$ vmtoolsd --cmd "info-get myTest"  
Invalid key name supplied  
$ vmware-cmd --config esxi-24 "[DS_104.24_150] LTSP2/LTSP2.vmx" setguestinfo guestinfo.myTest "bla-bla-bla"  
setguestinfo(guestinfo.myTest bla-bla-bla) = 1  
$ vmware-cmd --config esxi-24 "[DS_104.24_150] LTSP2/LTSP2.vmx" getguestinfo guestinfo.myTest  
getguestinfo(guestinfo.myTest) = bla-bla-bla  
$ vmtoolsd --cmd "info-get guestinfo.myTest"  
bla-bla-bla
```

Meaning you'd need assistance from your virtualisation team to get that information displayed as you need it.

However at that point you may as well just get them to run a script to extract that information in a way that doesn't require them to hack about with configuration files of all their production servers (and probably have to reboot everything too).

eg in PowerCLI

```
Get-VM | Get-VMAdvancedConfiguration -key virtualHW.version
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! The powercli option is probably best, but I knew there had to be another way.